# RSA Signing using MD5-SHA1 Hash Algorithm

Tags: c#, ssl, rsa, md5, sha1

From what I can tell, TLS 1.1 requires the contents of the CertificateVerify message to be a digitally signed value using the concatenation of two hash algorithms (MD5 and SHA1). Is this possible to do in .NET using the RSACryptoServiceProvider?

This does not work:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(...);
    rsa.SignData(data, new MD5SHA1());
}
```

This also does not work:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(...);
    rsa.SignHash(new MD5SHA1().ComputeHash(data), "MD5SHA1");
}
```

(MD5SHA1 is an implementation of HashAlgorithm.)

Presumably this does not work because the signature embeds the OID of the hash algorithm, and MD5-SHA1 does not have a valid OID. Is this possible in .NET? Am I misunderstanding TLS 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else, I used the BigInteger class to make this work. What is called "signing" in TLS 1.1 is really just private-key encryption, which can be done using BigInteger math.

**Sign**

```
var hash = new MD5SHA1().ComputeHash(data);
var input = new BigInteger(hash);
return input.ModPow(new BigInteger(privateExponent),
                    new BigInteger(modulus)).GetBytes();
```

**Verify**

```
var hash = new MD5SHA1().ComputeHash(data);
var input = new BigInteger(signature);
var output = input.ModPow(new BigInteger(publicExponent),
                          new BigInteger(modulus)).GetBytes();
var rehash = SubArray(output, output.Length - 36);
return SequencesAreEqual(hash, rehash);
```

**Note** that you still have to add padding yourself to the output. (0x0001FFFFFF...FF00{data})

Signing can be optimized using CRT parameters (p, q, etc.), but that's a problem for another day.

Comment: Also see Bernstein's [RSA signatures and Rabin-Williams signatures: the state of the art](https://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf). It provides a history of RSA-like signature schemes.