# Convert Python to .Net code for signing with MD5/RSA

Tags: python, cryptography, .net-core, md5

I found a code snipped on the Internet in Python and want to convert it to .NET Core:

```
import rsa

def sign(data):
    privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(KEY)
    signature = rsa.sign(str.encode(data), privkey, 'MD5')
    print(signature)
    return ''.join(["%02x" % x for x in signature]).strip()
```

It hashes the data with an PKCS1 private key. 
I tried the included functions and BouncyCastel but neither of those have a good documentation.
I think for a use with .NET Core I probably have to convert my key to XML.

Comment: Take a look at [RSA Encrypt using Python, Decrypt using C#](http://brantsteen.com/blog/rsa-encrypt-using-python-decrypt-using-c-sharp/) and hopefully that'll get you on the right track.

Comment: XML won’t do it, .NET Core doesn’t support the To/FromXmlString methods :)

Comment: Bouncy should be able to read PKCS#1 encoded private keys. Signature generation with MD5 - a known broken hash function for which collisions are easy to generate - what *could* possibly go wrong? Update your algorithms!

Comment: Also see [RSA Signing using MD5-SHA1 Hash Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19407581/608639) (and friends).

Comment: Uh, that would be the Bouncy Castle cryptographic library of course. Sorry, I'm getting too used to shorten it to "Bouncy".